# Deployment handling with Rabbit

Tags: deployment, rabbitmq, blue-green-deployment, canary-deployment

My application has rabbitMq which has multiple consumers[3] and i do round robing for consuming the messages .
At the moment i do canary deployment while deploying new version but this lands me in situation where the message can be consumed by any consumer [not just the canary one] and it creates problem .
[Also i want it to behave like this only while deployment all other times round robin is needed]

I know about green blue deployment process already but is there any other way to go about this problem ?